# Why is my unit test of my Silverlight XAML bindings is failing?

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, xaml, mvvm

I've got the following combobox defined:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCurrency" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding IsoCurrenciesList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
          SelectedValuePath="LocaleID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CurrencyId, Mode=TwoWay">
</ComboBox>
```

Where `IsoCurrenciesList` is an `IEnumerable<IsoCurrency>` - the type being defined by us and declared in the view model as:

```
private IEnumerable<IsoCurrency> isoCurrenciesList;
public IEnumerable<IsoCurrency> IsoCurrenciesList
{
    get { return isoCurrenciesList; }
    set
    {
        isoCurrenciesList = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsoCurrenciesList");
    }
}
```

My unit test creates an instance of the view and view model and sets up some dummy currency data in a local list:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit()
{
    _target = new View();

    _viewModel = new ViewModel();

    var ukp = new IsoCurrency { Code = "GBP", Description = "Pound Sterling", LocaleID = 826 };
    var usd = new IsoCurrency { Code = "USD", Description = "US Dollar", LocaleID = 840 };
    var eur = new IsoCurrency { Code = "EUR", Description = "Euro", LocaleID = 978 };
    _currencies = new List<IsoCurrency> { ukp, usd, eur };

    GetUIElement<Grid>("LayoutRoot").DataContext = _viewModel;
}

private T GetUIElement<T>(string name) where T : UIElement
{
    return (T)_target.FindName(name);
}
```

Then the test method is called. This should set the currency `ComboBox.Items` (via the `ItemsSource` property)

```
[Asynchronous]
[TestMethod]
public void TestCurrencySelection()
{
    _target.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Set the currency list explicitly
            _viewModel.IsoCurrenciesList = _currencies;

            var currencyCombo = GetUIElement<ComboBox>("cmbCurrency");
            // This assert fails as Items.Count == 0
            CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(currencyCombo.Items, _currencies, "Failed to data-bind currencies.");

            EnqueueTestComplete();
        };

    TestPanel.Children.Add(_target);
}
```

I've followed the guidelines on [Jeremy Likeness's blog](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/08/unit-testing-xaml-data-bindings-in.html) but I can't get the bindings test to pass.

I've tried testing the bindings of other properties - simple strings, booleans and integers but the changes made at either end aren't reflected to the other.

The only thing I can think of is that there is another step I need to do after adding the view to the `TestPanel` to "activate" the bindings, but I've no idea what it could be.

**UPDATE**

I should point out that the code works fine in the actual application. Based on the comments (particularly those from Adam Sills) it looks like the problem lies in the code I *haven't* posted - i.e. it's something in the way we've structured the XAML or there's a difference in the way we set the `DataContext`. At least I can concentrate my efforts in (hopefully) the right area.

It appears that the position of the control in the view *does* matter. The page XAML is something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        ...
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="activityControl" 
                           IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                           BusyContent="{Binding BusyContent}" >
        <Grid>
            ... The page definition including sub grids, stack panels
                and the combo box I'm testing along with other controls

            <ops:SaveConfirmation Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
                                  x:Name="saveConfirmation"
                                  SavedState="{Binding VendorSaved, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:BusyIndicator/>
</Grid>
```

The `BusyIndicator` is the one from the Silverlight Toolkit and `SaveConfirmation` is a control we've written.

If I test the `IsBusy` binding on the `BusyIndicator` that works as expected. However, if I test the `SavedState` binding on the `SaveConfirmation` that fails - I set the `VendorSaved` property to true in the test but when I get the control the bound value is false.

```
var busyIndicator = GetUIElement<BusyIndicator>("activityControl");
Assert.AreEqual(busyIndicator.IsBusy, _viewModel.IsBusy, "Failed to data-bind busy indicator.");

var saveConfirmation = GetUIElement<SaveConfirmation>("saveConfirmation");
Assert.AreEqual(saveConfirmation.SavedState, _viewModel.VendorSaved, "Failed to data-bind saved state");
```

So the first test passes, but the second fails.

**What do I need to do to ensure that the bindings of elements all the way down the tree are set up?**

Comment: I took your code, eliminated Vendor, created an incredibly simple view with just a Grid "LayoutRoot" and a ComboBox and the test passes great (and Items.Count == 3).

Comment: @Adam - Ah yes `Vendor` left over from a attempt to test other bindings. The fact that it works is good news - it should work. So it appears the problem's in what I *haven't* posted.

Comment: FWIW - XAML: http://textsnip.com/ec7b6a ViewModel: http://textsnip.com/cec377 Test: http://textsnip.com/d32a77

Comment: Is it only the unittest that fails, or does it also fail in the real world?

Comment: @Bubblewrap - it's only the unit test that fails. Everything works in the real world. Given that Adam Sills got it to work with a simple view and viewmodel there must be something in the code I haven't posted that's causing the problem. At least I know where to look now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included the XAML for your ComboBox, but not the rest of your page. In your test you have `GetUIElement<Grid>("LayoutRoot").DataContext = _viewModel;`. In the example you're following, he defines:

```
<Grid x:Uid="LayoutRoot" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator},Path=Cascadia}">
```

and then the controls on which he's testing the bindings are nested directly inside that grid. Is your page setup the same way?

Comment: I assumed that was for the normal binding which we do in the view's constructor. I'll have to double check when I get into work tomorrow - but it might be promising line of enquiry.

Comment: The combobox isn't directly on the page, but `GetUIElement` finds the correct control as the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties have the expected values.

Comment: Hmm - it appears that the position of the control *does* matter. If I test the binding of a control that's directly under the `LayoutRoot` it works. As soon as I put something else in the way if fails.

Comment: Try changing `GetUIElement<Grid>("LayoutRoot")` to whatever is the parent control of your `ComboBox`.

Comment: @Joel - good idea, but the problem isn't that I'm not finding the control I want to test, but that the binding hasn't been set up when the `Loaded` event fires. I've made progress and I'll probably post an answer with the results when I've sorted out the last remaining problems.

Comment: Right, if it weren't finding the control it would throw a null reference exception. I think the problem though is with the binding path. Right now you're setting your ViewModel as the DataContext of your top-level Grid. Since your ComboBox isn't nested directly under that Grid, it's not able to bind correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's because you're doing `_viewModel.IsoCurrenciesList = _currencies;` in the Loaded handler instead of filling an existing ObservableCollection property like the example from the blog does. It is possible that the binding will not be updated till after the current call on the Dispatcher completes. Though i'm not familiar enough with Silverlight to say this for sure.

To test this, you could try setting `_viewModel.IsoCurrenciesList` before you set the viewModel as the DataContext on your control.

Comment: +1 - the binding for the IsoCurrenciesList won't evaluate and populate the items list until after the current method finishes. Why not just set the IsoCurrenciesList inside the TestInit? Are you testing your binding or are you testing your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation? You don't have to be testing both at the same time.

Comment: @Adam - We're looking at testing the binding, the INotifyPropertyChanged is tested elsewhere. Though I originally had the `IsoCurrenciesList` being set before setting the `DataContext` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Joel C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310112/joel-c) and [Adam Sills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13322/adam-sills) I've got this working.

The clue was that in the example the controls that were being tested were direct children of the `LayoutRoot` and indeed when I tested these controls on my page these tests passed too.

So I have two solutions:

1) Change the event on which the tests fire:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Tests that the currency ComboBox is databound correctly")]
public void TestCurrencySelection()
{
    _target.LayoutUpdated += (s, e) =>
        {
            SetupViewModel();

            var currencyCombo = GetUIElement<ComboBox>("cmbCurrency");
            CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(currencyCombo.Items,
                                           _currencies,
                                           "Failed to data-bind currencies list.");

            Assert.AreEqual(currencyCombo.SelectedValue,
                            _viewModel.CurrencyId,
                            "Failed to data-bind selected currency.");
        };

    TestPanel.Children.Add(_target);
}
```

The bindings aren't initialised until after the view is `Loaded` but they are by the time `LayoutUpdated` fires. By making this change I can now reliably test the bindings at any level of the visual tree.

This would be OK if I were testing all the bindings on the page in one test - which isn't really good practice.

2) Use the parent `UIElement` of the control I'm testing instead of `LayoutRoot` and still handle the `Loaded` event. This means that I have to add names to each of these container elements, but it does mean I can split the tests up more logically.