# Silverlight XAML binding is throwing Null Reference Exception

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

My qusetion is in continuation with previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217435/why-is-my-unit-test-of-my-silverlight-xaml-bindings-is-failing)  I have my combo box placed within other child grid, named "grid_SortPart". So, I have tried to set GetUIElement("grid_SortPart").DataContext = _viewModel; which somehow didn't work for me.

I have also tried changing _target.Loaded to _target.LayoutUpdated, but still same problem exists. During debugging I found that, I am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for object _target.

Following is my code I setted up by referring [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217435/why-is-my-unit-test-of-my-silverlight-xaml-bindings-is-failing).Please suggest me the thing which I did wrong along with the way to correct it out.

```
public ObservableCollection<ReturnStatus> _status;
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit()
{
  _target = new EfileView();
  efvm = new EfileViewModel();
  var p1 = new ReturnStatus { Status = "Completed" };
  var p2 = new ReturnStatus { Status = "Not Completed" };
  _status = new ObservableCollection<ReturnStatus> { p1, p2 };
  GetUIElement<Grid>("grid_SortPart").DataContext = efvm;
}

private T GetUIElement<T>(string name) where T : UIElement
{ return (T)_target.FindName(name); }

[Asynchronous]
[TestMethod]
public void TestCurrencySelection()
{
  _target.LayoutUpdated += (s, e) => 
   {
     // Set the currency list explicitly
     efvm.ItemSource_ReturnStatus = _status;
     var currencyCombo = GetUIElement<ComboBox>("cmb_Returns_2");
     // This assert fails as Items.Count == 0     
     CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(currencyCombo.Items, _status, "Failed to data-bind currencies.");
      EnqueueTestComplete();
    };
    TestPanel.Children.Add(_target);
}
```